# Proxy debugging tool doesn't capture traffic from some online games

Tags: debugging, android, proxy

I'm analyzing Android games with Fiddler 2 to see how the game collects data.
There is a problem, both Fiddler 2 and Charles Proxy doesn't capture any traffic from some online games. All i got are ads traffics.

I have ensure that I have enabled proxy on Android system, have certificate installed, filtered target process and check if https decryption is working. All fine. I have reseted cert and fiddler 2 but it doesn't help

I have heard it uses socket system, i don't know excatly what he meant.
This online game requests a lot of data. I checked logcat and i see that the game retrieved some json data but there is not enough infomation.

I'm missing something there?

[image]

Comment: Use iptables. Check out http://blog.dornea.nu/2015/02/19/redirect-androids-traffic-to-burp/

Comment: Proxies are easy to circumvent/not support. If you need better network analysis i suggest you set up a proper man in the middle.

Comment: Tried iptables but the game failed to connect. Viewing https websites still working fine. I don't know what to do since i'm quite new to MITM. I just want to see game request/response

Comment: In case your target makes use of ‚websockets‘, then OWASP ZAP can help intercept its traffic. Here‘s a guide https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_WebSockets_(OTG-CLIENT-010)

Comment: You can try to launch game using [frida](https://frida.re/) and load one of ssl unpin scripts ([1](https://codeshare.frida.re/@pcipolloni/universal-android-ssl-pinning-bypass-with-frida/), [2](https://codeshare.frida.re/@segura2010/android-certificate-pinning-bypass/), [3](https://codeshare.frida.re/@avltree9798/universal-android-ssl-pinning-bypass/), [4](https://codeshare.frida.re/@sowdust/universal-android-ssl-pinning-bypass-2/), [etc.](https://codeshare.frida.re/browse)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another software called HTTP Debugger. It does way better job capture everything that others couldn't. It is a paid software, but it's really worth for me

https://www.httpdebugger.com/

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler and Charles Proxy are web debugging proxies so they only capture http/s traffic. If the game doesn't use the http protocol the trafic wont appear in these tools.

Comment: Then what tools can capture the traffic? I found other games that doesn't use http/s protocol

Comment: Here are some suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark#9570093

Answer (score 0):

I believe Burp by [PortSwinger](https://portswigger.net/) will do the work.

How to configure Android to work with Burp: https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841101-configuring-an-android-device-to-work-with-burp

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It also not showing anything